# Unable to connect to Azure MySQL Database through Azure Function - C#

Tags: c#, mysql, azure, azure-functions

I am trying to connect to Azure's MySQL Database (preview) from an Azure function I am creating. However, when I try opening the connection I get an error saying `Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream`.

My Function code looks like this:

```
#r "System.Data"    <--- Uploaded System.Data.dll into the root folder
#r "MySql.Data"     <--- Uploaded MySql.Data.dll (6.9) into root folder

using MySql.Data; 
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
{
    var connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQL_Conn"].ConnectionString;
    using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        try{
            conn.Open();
            log.Info("Connection opened");
        }catch(Exception ex){
            log.Info("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
    //log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
}
```

Troubleshooting the error, this is what I have tried so far:

- Copied the connection string and tried it with MySQL Workbench and it worked fine
- Added the IP Address of my function's application to MySQL allowed IP List.

None of these method worked for me.

I would be glad if someone can point me in the right direction since most of the guides out there is meant for SQL Server and not MySQL with C#.

Thank you

Comment: You would be glad if you can be pointed to SQL Server? I don't get it. Please rewrite. Error itself: Add your connect string (without passwords). Check your mysql user if it is allowed to connect from the IP from your app too while you are at it.

Comment: My question is about Azure MySQL and Azure functions. I stated in the question that my connection string works fine. so I wanted someone to assist in solving this issue because I can't seem to find a guide related to Azure functions with MySQL. This is how my connection string looks like: `Server={your_servername}; Port=3306; Database={your_database}; Uid={your_username}; Pwd={your_password}; SslMode=Preferred;`

Comment: Given you have console app that you verify locally.   Try run the same on kudu console (https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console) to isolate rule out if Azure WebApps or Functions specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get an error saying `Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream`.

I could reproduce the issue on my side. It seems that the version of MySql.Data cause the issue, if I [upload project.json file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#using-nuget-packages) that adds a reference to`MySql.Data "7.0.7-m61"`, I could connect to MySQL Database (preview).

***project.json***

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46":{
      "dependencies": {
        "MySql.Data": "7.0.7-m61"
      }
    }
   }
}
```

***Function code and Logs***

[image]